# Is there a way to pause a script until ffmpeg finishes converting a file?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, converters, pause

I have a python script that uploads a file to the cloud prematurely (before it finishes being converted to ogg), how can I pause the script until the conversion finishes without using something like time.sleep?

```
    cmd = ("ffmpeg -i " + mp4_file + " -y -loglevel quiet -ar 16000 -ac 1 -acodec libopus -vn " + audio_file)
    os.popen(cmd)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `subprocess.run` to block until it is done.

On Python 3.5 and older you should use `subprocess.call`.